# Mybatis(iBatis) XML mapping configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis 3.2.2 and I have problems loading XML mappers as resources.

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="src/main/resources/Conference.xml" />
</mappers>
```

#### Exception

`nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource src/main/resources/Conference.xml`

Project is builed by Maven.

Comment: Try specifying the package name by itself, if your source folder is "src", it would just be `main/resources/Conference.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Maven, so you can leave off the `src/main/resources` path altogether, as `Conference.xml` will be found at the root of your classpath. This should work:

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="Conference.xml" />
</mappers>
```

Comment: Cause I got exception parsing Conference.xml so I think problem is solved. The resource was found. And mybatis-config.xml, and all mappers xml configs are in the same `src/main/resources` folder.